# Proxmox on localhost network + 32 bits host

Tags: localhost, proxmox, 32-bit, i386

I'm working in installing Proxmox on localhost network.

Installing the PVE kernel works fine :

```
root@localhost:~# uname -a
Linux localhost 2.6.32-14-pve #1 SMP Sat Sep 22 08:55:13 EST 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file :

```
root@localhost:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  localhost
192.168.1.30   localhost localhost localdev
::1        ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0        ip6-localnet
ff00::0        ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1        ip6-allnodes
ff02::2        ip6-allrouters
```

But when I type apt-get install proxmox-ve-2.6.32 I got :

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

proxmox-ve-2.6.32 :
    Depends: pve-kernel-2.6.32-26-pve but it is not installable
    Depends: pve-manager but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: qemu-server but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: pve-qemu-kvm but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: vzctl (>= 3.0.29) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So what can I do for installing this on my 32-bits hosts on local network ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, you only can install Proxmox 2 on a 32-bit system on Debian Squeeze (https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_Squeeze_on_32-Bit_Processor), but Proxmox 3 on Debian Wheezy can only be installed on a 64-bit system.